# What kind of window glazing is this?

Tags: windows

I need to replace a broken window pane and have been watching several DIY videos on the subject. There are so many glazing types to secure in the windows and I'm wondering if anyone can tell me what type of glazing this is and if this is a common easy DIY project.

[image]

Comment: If you can, carefully pull off glass to expose the inner edge, and then post a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick guess from a blurry picture, that looks like a double-pane "thermal glass" unit (very common in modern windows) and probably  requires taking the sash it is in (aluminum or vinyl?) out of the windowframe and dissassembling to replace.

Anything involving glazing putty and points almost certainly does not apply here.